# Rule conflict in Jess rule engine

Tags: jess

I use Jess rule engine and i have some rules which change some slot values as a conclusion.This is achieved with two different ways:
1.with Jess modify (e.g.=>modify fact)
2.with a jess function (e.g. => change(slotvalue))
The problem is when two rules change the same slotvalue. I use Jess salience for this and it works ok only for type 1=>modify fact.
When i have a rule with the function,the rule is excecuted every time.How can i solve this?

Here is the code:

1)if person is student=>(modify  ?fact( fredo 2))
2) if day is Wednesday=>(modify  ?fact ( fredo (discount (fact-slot-value ?fact fredo) 50)))
3)if time >5 =>(modify  ?fact( fredo 5))

if  a person is student,day is wednsesday and time >5 then all rules are fired and fredo slot value will be 5 because this rule fired last. 
How can i solve priority issues in this case (e.g to fire only the second rule);  is it possible;
Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Can you explain more what "change(slotvalue)" does? I have an idea what your problem may be, but I'm not sure I understand.

Comment: Hello Mr Hill,it is a discount function  -> deffunction discount (?n ?n1) (return (- ?n (* ?n (/ ?n1 100))))),  which takes a slot value as an argument

Comment: Ok, now I really have no idea what you mean. Can you edit your post  to add some code that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: I'm sorry, I still am not really sure what you're asking without a full example. Including either of these functions on the right-hand-side of a rule will have no effect on rule priorities (salience). You say something about "the rule is executed every time", but you don't say what rule we're talking about there. It is true that executing either one of these may force pattern-matching to be redone for any rules that match this fact. Anyway, if you can include an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) then I can probably help.